# Limit is not working for AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, documentclient

I have a lambda function to fetch the items from dynamoDB. I have already set `Limit: 100` but its not working and it gives the response as `413 - Payload Too Large`.

Here is my code and I am using it with `documentClient.query`:

```
   {
      TableName: <tableName>,
      IndexName: <index-value>',
      ScanIndexForward: false,  
      KeyConditionExpression: '#status = :status',
      FilterExpression: filterExpression,
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#status": "status"
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: expressionAttributeValues,
      Limit: 100
    };
```

Kindly share your inputs.

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt if the error is from query operation? A Query operation can retrieve a maximum of 1 MB of data. This limit applies before the filter expression is evaluated and will return fewer items when size is reached. If this query api is erroring, possibly check the "expressionAttributeValues" - this may have more values breaching API payload limit

Comment: In my experience, the 413 Payload Too Large means that your **request**, not the response, was too large. Please try to print your request and see that it doesn't contain a huge amount of nonsense.